# React toggling between two images on click in stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react stateless component with two images which I wish to toggle onClick but can't seem to make it work.

I don't wish to use a class component, as I wish to keep things simple.

```
import selected from 'images/selected.svg'
import deselected from 'images/deselected.svg'

const CheckBox = ({ handleClick }) => {

  let checked = false
  let getSelectedSVG = deselected

  const toggleCheck = () => {
    checked = !checked
    if (checked) {
      getSelectedSVG = selected
    } else {
      getSelectedSVG = deselected
    }
    handleClick()
  }

  let checkbox = getSelectedSVG
  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={toggleCheck}>
        <span><img alt={'svtp-Checkbox'} src={checkbox} /></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CheckBox
```

Comment: Even if its not a class component, you still need some sort of state in order for the component to re-render and reflect your changes.

Comment: you can use react hooks useState  in functional components.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to get around using state, which is going to lead to disaster and disappointment. You have to use state to track... well, the state of the component. With hooks, you can keep it a functional component.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const CheckBox = ({ handleClick }) => {

  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

  const toggleCheck = () => {
    setIsChecked(!isChecked);
    handleClick()
  }

  const checkbox = isChecked ? selected : deselected;
  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={toggleCheck}>
        <span><img alt={'svtp-Checkbox'} src={checkbox} /></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Still a simple, functional component. One small piece of state. Not trying to bend the rules of React.

Comment: Awesome, and my first use of hooks!